# How do I control the color of an SVG drop-shadow?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have the following SVG:

```
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="2" dy="2"></feOffset>
        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"></feBlend>
    </filter>
</defs>
```

How, though, would I alter it to add the ability to control the color of the shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an feColorMatrix element. Try experimenting with the numbers in the values attribute.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300px">
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" width="130%" height="130%">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="5" dy="5"></feOffset>
        <feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix"
      values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 1 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"></feBlend>
    </filter>
</defs>
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" fill="red" filter="url(#dropshadow)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can't get it to work in Chrome MSIE(11) nor FF. . I have this in my SVG code: <feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix" values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 1 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>

Comment: The code snippet in the answer certainly works in FF because that's what I used to create and test it. Seems OK in Chrome too, lime green shadow there also. Note there are other changes e.g. SourceAlpha in your feOffset is SourceGraphic in mine.

Comment: depends on what values you use in the feColorMatrix

Comment: Interesting. I was using JavaScript to create the SVG elements but now I've tried using it in a standalone HTML file it works. Making the matrix is going to take some thought though.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the fixed offset column in a feColorMatrix to specify an exact color. Specifically, if you want, for example, RGB(128,128,0) then you convert this to the unit scale (0.5, 0.5,0) and put it in the fifth column of your color matrix. It's also important that you're specifying this in sRGB color space.

```
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="2" dy="2"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="offOut" result ="matrixOut" type="matrix"                           
                                     values="0 0 0 0 0.5
                                             0 0 0 0 0.5
                                             0 0 0 0 0 
                                             0 0 0 1 0" />
        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="2"/>
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
```